# Sci-fi book about a male entering a competition that he wins and gets recruited by millitary

Tags: story-identification, books

Sci-fi book in the future about a city that had 2 levels.

The top level was for the rich people. A game center with a space flight game is added. The main character (male) plays with friends and wins a competition. He ends up in huge competition and does well. He finds his sister (twin I believe) and joins the military as the competition was just a recruitment game. He flies into "destroyed land" and finds out that rich barons are living on private islands.  The destroyed lands were caused by some plague.

I read this book in 2010.

Comment: dang - I read that book when it was called "Ender's Game" - this one sounds interesting too.... : |

Comment: Enders Game is also really good.

Comment: Also reminiscent of the movie "The Last Starfighter"

Comment: That city sounds like Midgar.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Could this be the 2009 book *[The Roar](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4837032-the-roar)* by Emma Clayton?

[image: Book cover]

> In the future, a **plague** spreads through all the world's animals. To survive, the humans create a northern wall through Canada, England, etc. Every living thing south of the wall is destroyed while all the people in the world move north of the wall into multi-leveled cities with no plants or animals. Their food is produced from chemicals and mold.
>
> Because of the lack of space, it's 30 years before anyone is allowed to have children. **2 of these children are fraternal twins** Ellie and Mika. When Ellie disappears, Mika's parents believe that she's dead. But the strong telepathic bond Mika shares with his twin leads him to believe that she's alive, and he'll do anything to find her again. This leads him to follow along with what the government demands of him even when he senses there's some secret the government is trying to hide from everyone. This includes joining his classmates in learning **war games on simulators** and competing in competitions that can make his family very rich.

In another review:

> The world behind The Wall was divided into two; the rich live in the upper level known as The Golden Turrets while the poor live on the lower level, The Shadows.

Comment: i just asked this question and it was the roarhttps://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157271/book-about-a-boy-who-plays-a-video-game-that-turns-out-to-be-a-job-interview?noredirect=1#comment472983_157271

Comment: Yup. That's why I marked it as a duplicate. :)