# Book about a boy who plays a video game that turns out to be a job interview

Tags: story-identification, games

The plot goes like this: a boy goes to an arcade and plays a game with this girl. He is the pilot and she is the shooter. Somewhere in middle of the game they switch places. It turns out that the game was just a test to find someone to work for this company. They get recruited, and I do not remember what happens after that.

It is not *Ender's Game*.

Comment: Shades of "The Last Starfighter" and "Ender's Game"
When was the book read, written, language, etc...- the info here is helpful in making the question better: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question

Comment: Take a look at [this list](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and see if you can remember anything else about the book. You can [edit] your question to add details at any time.

Comment: Sounds like every kids' dream.

Comment: Could it be *Next* by James Hynes?

Comment: no i dont think so but thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was it *[The Roar](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4837032-the-roar)* by Emma Clayton? I think I read the same book and I can't find it anywhere, it's driving me crazy. I looked at *The Roar* and I've read it before, but I don't know if it's the right one.

> Mika and Ellie live in a future behind a wall: Solid concrete topped with high-voltage razor wire and guarded by a battalion of Ghengis Borgs, it was built to keep out the animals, because animals carry the plague. At least that's what Ellie, who was kidnapped as a child, has always been taught.
>
> But when she comes to suspect the truth behind her captivity, she's ready to risk exposure to the elements and answer the call of the wild. Listen. Can you hear it? She's strapping on her headset, jumpstarting her Pod Fighter, and--with her capuchin monkey at her back--she's breaking out!

Comment: Hi! It would be helpful to add some details that you remember from The Roar. The protagonist, what kind of game they play, other details of the world or plot, anything that you noticed was similar to the details in the question.

Comment: YES THATS IT thank you so much when i first saw that you suggested the roar i thought that it wasn't it because i thought that i had never read it. then i went to the library and took out the book. this has been annoying me and my friend for at least a year. THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH

Answer (score 2):

Ooh ooh I think I know this one!

You are looking for *Molly Fyde and the Parsona Rescue*, by Hugh Howey.   It was flight academy she was kicked out of though, but there's a subplot about how she didn't know it was a test.  It involves pilot/shooter(navigator) and at one point they switch positions and she is expelled while he gets to advance.

Link ([Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1481222880)).

Comment: The OP says both of them are hired.

Comment: You're right.  In my defense, the story of the book complicates my simple summary and the boy and girl do end up working together.   Regardless, point taken.

Comment: sorry it looks like a good book but i have never read it. thank you anyways

Answer (score 2):

Kind of reminds me of [***Armada***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armada_(novel)) by Ernest Cline.

> Zack Lightman glances out his classroom window and spots a UFO. The ship he’s staring at is straight out of the video game he plays every night, a hugely popular online air combat simulator called Armada, in which gamers protect Earth from alien invaders. He is fairly skilled at the game, having placed in the top ten among millions of users, however in real life, he is just a high school senior with a reputation of having a short fuse and getting into trouble.
>
> He works part-time at a video game shop where his boss Ray surprises him with a fancy new controller for Armada as an early graduation gift. He tries it out on one of the new special missions on Armada that involves attacking the home planet of the aliens but the Earth team fails.
>
> Some time later a shuttlecraft with the Earth Defense Alliance (EDA) logo lands. Ray is one of the passengers, and he invites Zack to join him to a top-secret military facility in Nebraska.
>
> There, he learns the EDA is real, that there are actually aliens from Europa planning to invade the planet with ships as shown in the Armada game, and that the EDA had been using Armada to train soldiers to pilot drone ships to protect Earth from the Europans and to identify which gamers would be best for the task.

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armada_(novel)

Comment: i dont think i heard of this book before but thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The one I immediately thought of was The Last Starfighter, the first movie to use extensive computer graphics. The main character is recruited because he is really good at a video game.

Comment: it was definatley a book and in the last star fighter the girl doesnt come with him. but thank you so much