# Book about a kid who plays a space flight simulator at an arcade for a prize

Tags: story-identification, space, childrens-novel

So the book's cover has red and yellow caution tape around the edges and red for the rest of the cover; it's a short single word title. It's not *The Road*, *Ender's Game*, or *Armada*.

The book follows a kid in a post-apocalyptic city, where everything is pretty run-down. He's poor, but they only thing for fun around is an arcade where he plays a space fighting simulator, which he is very good at. There is a prize to go to a type of sanctuary or place and, long story short, he gets the prize with the help of a friend he meets at the arcade. When they get to the sanctuary, it turns out they can't leave or go back and everything is fake, so they escape in some type of spacecraft or plane.

After that, it gets blurry and I can't remember much. Sorry if it's not much to work with; I can remember most of the book, just not the title. I read the book as a kid, so it had to have come out around 2005-2011.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark, as per the [tour].

Comment: Single word title, so definately not "The Last Starfighter" (also trailer park not post apocalyptic)

Comment: Could it be the novelization of the film 'The Last Starfighter,' by Foster?

Answer (score 3):

Could this be Emma Clayton's *[The Roar](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4837032-the-roar)* (2008) as per [Sci-fi book about a male entering a competition that he wins and gets recruited by millitary](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150995/sci-fi-book-about-a-male-entering-a-competition-that-he-wins-and-gets-recruited/150997#150997)?

[image: Front cover of The Roar]

> Mika and Ellie live in a future behind a wall: Solid concrete topped with high-voltage razor wire and guarded by a battalion of Ghengis Borgs, it was built to keep out the animals, because animals carry the plague. At least that's what Ellie, who was kidnapped as a child, has always been taught.
>
> But when she comes to suspect the truth behind her captivity, she's ready to risk exposure to the elements and answer the call of the wild. Listen. Can you hear it? She's strapping on her headset, jumpstarting her Pod Fighter, and--with her capuchin monkey at her back--she's breaking out!

Not mentioned in the summary is that Ellie was kidnapped as a baby, and Mika and Ellie are unaware of each other's existence. Also not mentioned there is the salient plot point you mention, that Mika competes in VR combat simulations with his classmates that are competitions to enter the Academy.

Comment: As I said above it's not road but it's very similar and it came out around the same time

Comment: @Trevorm: This is *The Roar*, not *The Road*. :) But if it's not a match, it's not a match. Other than the title (and the lack of caution tape on the cover), can you think of other non-matching aspects you can edit into the question?