# Video Game competition brainwashes kids into soldiers

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

I remember reading this book when I was young but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

The plot follows a boy who embodies ADHD characteristics.
His school curriculum is programmed by a computer. For some reason he is punished and one of the punishments is to sort beads. He doesn't see it as a tedious task but a meditative activity.

There is a scene where he sees a cop car shining a light into his bedroom window, and upon seeing the boy in his sleeping wear, drives off.
The lower classes live in a different city than the higher classes. The high class city is built over the poor city and supported by giant concrete pillars.

There is a video game competition to win a vacation to the rich city. The main character signs up and starts moving up the ranks. He makes it to the top rank and is invited to a tropical themed resort in the rich city for the final match. He wins.

Afterwards, all the kids who played the game start attacking the general population because they were brainwashed into soldiers.
The main character wasn't brainwashed because of his ADHD-like characteristics.
In response, rebels attack the pillars trying to topple the rich city.
The main character's family return home trying to escape the conflict setting up for a possible sequel.

The book was essentially a combination of *Ender's Game* and *Divergent*.

Comment: We don't know when you were young, roughly how many years ago did you read this?

Comment: Shades of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150995/sci-fi-book-about-a-male-entering-a-competition-that-he-wins-and-gets-recruited?noredirect=1&lq=1, but there's a more explicit recruitment to being a soldier.

Comment: I was in fifth grade. I found the book at the school library in the semi-advanced section. I don't know the reading level.